# Can't get data from Shared Service that depends on Websocket

Tags: angular, websocket, socket.io

On the component load I make a call to my websocket function that asks the server for the character list

Menu Component ->

```
constructor(private router: Router, public shared: SharedService, private wss: WebsocketService) {
    this.wss.emitGetCharacters();
}
```

Websocket Service -->

```
// Get Character List
public emitGetCharacters(): any {
    if (!this.socket) {
        this.initSocket();
        this.socket.emit('getCharacters', this.idUser);
    } else {
        this.socket.emit('getCharacters', this.idUser);
    }
}
```

Then the server returns the characters correctly on the websocket service which uses the shared service to store the character list

```
    this.socket.on('characterList', (res) => {
        this.shared.setCharacters(res);
    });
```

Then on ngOnInit from my menu component I try to get the characters using the shared function

```
public getCharacters() {
    return this.characters;
}
```

This returns undefined

I know this has to do with Observables and RxJS and but i've been reading and I cant understand how to implement it on this case

Comment: Do you need to subscribe to `this.shared.setCharacters(res)`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean @R.Richards

Comment: I am assuming that `this.shared.setCharacters(res)` returns an Observable. If you don't subscribe to it, it will never return anything, it will not run. Does it return an Observable?

Comment: public setCharacters(data) {
            this.characters = data
    }

This is what setCharacters its doing right now @R.Richards

Comment: I see, it returns nothing (void). Not sure what the issue is.